# Edit a function into 0xdbe

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function, datagrip

Recently I started to use 0xdbe. I appreciate so much, but I don't know how to edit a function. I can't see a DDL function into 0xdbe.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: So? Did you solve it?

Comment: Yeap. Dawid answered.

Comment: Tags for this question should be updated. 0xdbe is now Datagrip and should be marked as such to improve searching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a database tree expand "routines" and double click function you want to change. It opens function editor, where you can change it and then click green "play" button in top right corner, which executes it. That's all.

Comment: Thanks Dawid. Do you know how I can print logs like "notices" using plpgsql?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by printing logs. Logs of what? Also PL/pgSQL is just a language similar to SQL, but for creating a stored procedures. It's output is the same as output of plain SQL query. So I have no idea, what do you mean by printing. Anyway you should create a separate question if you need a help on another topic.